# Can UIApplication.shared.applicationState be reliably called from a non-main thread?

Tags: ios, swift

I have a piece of code that runs in a scheduled timer (about every 7 seconds) that downloads an image from the network, crops it, and displays it in a UIImageView.

I'm using GPUImage2 to help with this, however this means (obviously) it uses the GPU to do so.

The problem is that i'm getting random crashes when performing the gpu-based crop when the app is in the background.

I've implemented a bunch of code to stop the timer when the app is heading to the background to prevent this condition.  However there is a condition where the app goes to the background while the network request is happening, and thus I need to check to see if the app is in the background (or more formally, not in the foreground) just before performing the image cropping.

I'm using this code (which may be in a non-main thread):

```
guard (UIApplication.shared.applicationState == UIApplicationState.active) else {
    return
}
// perform GPU operation here.
```

However, I'm still getting the random crash report.  It's possible that there's a race between when the `guard` statement occurs and when the GPU operation happens, but that seems very unlikely and I'm getting quite a few crash reports  from this section of code.

I'm wondering if there's a thread problem where the UIApplication.shared.applicationState should really only be read on the main thread, and since i'm not on the main thread, the value is incorrect (saying the application is active when really it's not), but the docs don't give any indication either way.

What do you think?

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46278957/main-thread-checker-ui-api-called-on-a-background-thread-ios-11-xcode-9-gm-seed

Answer (score 1):

The best option is to code defensively. Most UIKit methods are not thread safe, so it is safe to assume `UIApplication.shared.applicationState` may only work from the main thread.

A simple solution is to ensure you are on the main thread, for example:

```
DispatchQueue.main.async {
    guard UIApplication.shared.applicationState == .active else {
        return
    }
    // perform GPU operation here, possibly within another DispatchQueue to execute in the background
}
```

Answer (score 0):

[image]You are probably correct. Try running in Xcode 9 where it will likely flag this as an illegal operation - calling on main thread - and issue a runtime warning.